# Web proxy with SSH Tunnel to Ubuntu 12.04 with Putty is refusing connections

Tags: ssh-tunnel, putty

I'm trying to set up a SSH tunnel via Putty so I can access my router admin pages.

I have an ubuntu 12.04 machine on the local network with SSH access.

I can SSH into that ubuntu box (that sits on the same network as the router i'm trying to get to).

So this is what I'm doing for my SSH tunnel

In Putty.

- Create an SSH Tunnel Of Auto Location: Dynamic Port, Port Number 9999 (then clicking add)
- I see the port D9999
- I then make a connection to the remote machine with Putty (over port 22) and I log in to the remote machine.

In Firefox

I set the connection to socks5 proxy at localhost port 9999

Now when I try and connect to any web site in firefox it says

```
The proxy server is refusing connections
Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.
```

While I'm SSH'd into the remote box, I can do telnet www.google.com 80 and that connects just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include PuTTY event log.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, me being dumb

I had "localhost" set up in my /etc/hosts file to point to a local VM

sorry for the time waste